# How to connect GUI screens in Android ? 

Tags: android

How to connect GUI screens in Android? I have created several screens and I want to connect these using buttons.

Comment: You should read about `Intents`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what else you want to do by clicking a button. If you only want to click a button and go to next activity or you want to send some data to next activity. Or maybe you want to dial a number or view contacts etc.

Here's a nice tutorial about using `startActivity()` and `startActivityForResult()` methods - [android startActivity and startActivityForResult](http://saiful103a.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/android-startactivity-and-startactivityforresult/)

Also basic [Intents Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

just take a event handler .. in that use INTENT 
 Here s the syntax , startActivity(Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);

ex: 
`Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(activity.this, activity2.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
     });`

Here !st activity1 i..e.. ur current class(1st page) name

Comment: i mean can the current class be XML file ?

Comment: No its in main class file,  U just add a new class in the same source of the package and create a xml file for this class as ur requirement and in the intent syntax U just mention this class_name.class instead of activity2.class....

Comment: how do i add a new class to the same the same package...its showing error:Invalid ZIP archive: src/net/learn2develop/GoogleMaps/Services.java [in GoogleMaps]

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IE2LIFniNhQ&feature=related


     go through this , U will come to know easily...  Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

Intent is the best mechanism to connect your component(activties, services) run time. [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you can find about intent class.